# Dynamic Javascript form input not POSTing

Tags: javascript, flask

I am working on a web application using the python-flask framework.

A trouble I am having is on a form where the user can create new input fields. The forms appear in the HTML code, and visually appear in the browser, however the elements that are created dynamically do not appear in the POST request.

Below is two javascript functions, the first creates the form element when the user pushes the appropriate button. The second code I found online, because it said that the serialize would add the Dynamic form elements to the POST request.

```
$(function create_new_row_plus_button_fn() {
$("#addRows").click(function () {
            counter = counter + "a";
            var trelem = document.createElement('tr');
            var tdelem = document.createElement('td');
            trelem.appendChild(tdelem);
            var frm = document.getElementById("new_table_id");
            var newEl = document.createElement("input");
            newEl.name = counter;
            newEl.type = "text";
            tdelem.appendChild(newEl);
            frm.appendChild(trelem);
    });
})

$('#form_container').on('submit', function(e) {
    //prevent the default submithandling
    e.preventDefault();
    //send the data of 'this' (the matched form) to yourURL
    $.post('/add_new_product', $(this).serialize());
    location.reload();
});
```

One thing that I notice is that if I view html from the chrome debugger, the dynamic form elements are viewable, but if I look at the page source they are not.

Comment: Page source only shows what was sent from server and will never show anything created or modified with javascript in the dom

Comment: Can you check if `$(this).serialize()` is actually including your elements? If not, can you show us how your DOM looks like after adding a few rows. I have a feeling those dynamic inputs are NOT under your `<form>` element.

Comment: The problem was that the form element was under the table element, for some reason. Once I put the <form> on the outside of the <table>, it worked as intended. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score -1):

The problem occurred from having the  element inside of the . Moving the  outside the  fixed the issue.

Comment: This answer needs more nouns.